# 8 Byte Number as Hex in C

Tags: c, hex, printf

I have given a number, for example n = 10, and I want to calculate its length in hex with big endian and save it in a 8 byte char pointer. In this example I would like to get the following string:
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50".
How do I do that automatically in C with for example sprintf?
I am not even able to get "\x50" in a char pointer:

```
char tmp[1];
sprintf(tmp, "\x%x", 50); // version 1
sprintf(tmp, "\\x%x", 50); // version 2
```

Version 1 and 2 don't work.

Comment: Decimal 50 in hex is 0x32, so I'm not sure why you expect it to be 0x50...

Comment: `char tmp[1];` => too short for any 1-sized nul termninated string

Comment: I want to calculate the decimal n=10 in hex and that is 0x50 and I want to save it in a char pointer with sprintf such that the string is "\x50".

    char tmp[2]; 
    sprintf(tmp, "\\x%x", 50);
    tmp[1] = 0;

doesn't work either.

Comment: Decimal 10 isn't hex 50: it is hex 0A.  50 is hex 32.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. n=10, that are 0x0a bytes or 0x50 bits. I want ti represent n in bits as hex.

Comment: `char tmp[2]` is still too short. It can only store 1-character string

Comment: But char tmp[1]; tmp[0]="\x50"; works fine in the program.

Answer (score 1):

> I have given a number, for example n = 10, and I want to calculate its length in hex

Repeatedly divide by 16 to find the number of hexadecimal digits.  A `do ... while` insures the result is 1 when `n==0`.

```
int hex_length = 0;
do {
  hex_length++;
} while (number /= 16);
```

> save it in a 8 byte `char` pointer.

C cannot force your system to use 8-byte pointer.  So if you system uses 4 byte `char` pointer, we are out of luck.  Let us assume OP's system uses 8-byte pointer.  Yet integers may be assigned to pointers.  This may or may not result in valid pointer.

```
assert(sizeof (char*) == 8);
char *char_pointer = n;
printf("%p\n", (void *) char_pointer);
```

> In this example I would like to get the following string: `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50"`.

In C, a *string* includes the various characters up to an including a *null character*. `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50"` is not a valid C *string*, yet is a valid *string literal*. Code cannot construct *string literals* at run time, that is a part of source code. Further the relationship between `n==10` and `"\x00...\x00\x50"` is unclear.  Instead perhaps the goal is to store `n` into a 8-byte array (big endian).

```
char buf[8];
for (int i=8; i>=0; i--) {
  buf[i] = (char) n;
  n /= 256;
}
```

---

OP's code certainly will fail as it attempts to store a *string*  which is too small.  Further `"\x%x"` is not valid code as `\x` begins an invalid escape sequence.

```
char tmp[1];
sprintf(tmp, "\x%x", 50); // version 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
int i;
...
int length = round(ceil(log(i) / log(16)));
```

This will give you (in `length`) the number of hexadecimal digits needed to represent `i` (without `0x` of course).

`log(i) / log(base)` is the log-base of `i`. The log16 of `i` gives you the exponent.

To make clear what we're doing here: When rising 16 to the power of the found exponent, we get back `i`: 16^log16(i) = i.

By rounding up this exponent using `ceil()`, you get the number of digits.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want ti calculate the lenght I need to represent n. I want to represent n as a 64bit number in big endian by using 8 parts of ghr Form "\x..", for example "\x00" or "\x50".

Comment: @Cybergy But you literally write: "I want to calculate its length in hex"?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I wrote it wrong. I am sorry.  
I try to explain it better this time.  
I have given a string, lets say char *string = "message123". Then I calculate the length of the string: n = strlen(string). So n = 10. That are 0x0a bytes or 0x50 bits. I want to represent that as "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50" (in 64bit with big endian). What I want to do is the following: my input is a string like "message123" and the output should be "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x50".

Comment: Why do you think hex 50 represents decimal 10 ?

Comment: `ceil(log(i) / log(16))` risks an off-by-one given a slightly imprecise log  or division calculation.